# how to evaluate Jaccard Similarity coefficient metric of string by using Precision-recall

Tags: precision-recall

I am interested in text mining, so recently I am using jaccard similarity coefficient with Shingling to measuring the similarity between input information (for instance :Actimel Strawberry Yogurt Drink) and thousands of records in dataset. I ranked the results by similarity scores. These are the results.

[image: this is the results]

but I want to know if this jaccard metric is good for my measures, so I am going to use precision recall. What I know about precision recall curve is like below：

> precison = tp/tp+fp, recall = tp/tp+fn

I checked [scikitlearn.org](http://scikitlearn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html), it seems to use classifier, I don't know what exactly that y_test is (I guess it is test data for classifier)
how can I draw out this kind plot.

Comment: I checked this before https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-ranked-retrieval-results-1.html.

Comment: Maybe i get it wrong